# Can't edit Javascript method on-the-fly with Firebug

Tags: javascript, firebug

I'm opening the following page in Firefox with Firebug: www.example.com

Comment: Use **Chrome Developer Tool**, it allows you to update JavaScript on the fly

Comment: Firebug will allow you to update JavaScript on the fly also. You may want to console.log() everything that is coming out of the function so you can see exactly what is getting fired and what results it has.

Comment: @Munim Firebug has pretty much equivalent capabilities; there's no reason to prefer one over the other, other than the fact that Chrome's Developer Tools is built-in.

Comment: @mc10 I am a big fan of Firebug too - but I must admit once you start use CDT, you will like it over Firebug on some extra functionality and modifying JS on the fly

Comment: If it's declared as a variable inside another function - you can't overwrite it with Firebug from the console - it can never see it. I've done things like this many times with Fiddler autoresponder - why is it not a good solution for you? Is it not in an external javascript?