# how to edit javascript or jquery script with firebug?

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebug

We can edit the html and css with firebug or any other inspector but I'm surprised why could I not edit the javascript or jquery code. How can I edit the js code?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8272174/cant-edit-javascript-method-on-the-fly-with-firebug

Comment: never used chrome dev tools?? o__O ?? just go to Sources and open a file..

Comment: thanks but still can't edit the code.....

Comment: @NavinRauniyar i dont know why you can't... you just have to go to the Sources Tab.. Hit Ctrl+O to open a file.. and start editing.. worked for me..  ._.

Comment: Yeah, opened a file but couldn't edit